# Calling a method dynamically with the right arguments

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, mef

first of all, the answer is not

```
.Invoke("name", new object[] { });
```

:) that being said, i have some old generic code that creates context menus and hot keys handlers using definitions from a config file and executes the actual methods using .Invoke() where the method signature is pre-defined or else the method is not executed

e.g. the method signatures are all same with these arguments

```
   change_back_color( mycontext ctx, object sender, controlItemClickEventArgs e)
   {
           //...           
   }
```

I have to rework the code to include some additional functionality and would like to have Unity/MEF like functionality where the signature can include the required parameters only and order of arguments can be changed

e.g. the code can be changed to

```
   [FunctionKey("myKey1")]
   change_back_color( object sender, mycontext ctx )
   {
           //...           
   }
```

or

```
   [FunctionKey("myKey1")]
   change_back_color( mycontext ctx)
   {
           //...           
   }
```

Looking for guidance on how to go about it/where to look

UPDATE - the definitions are in db which can be retrieved like so

```
var commands = dbContext.GetCommands("current_view_name") ; // return method key, user roles etc.

// and i can use the following to match to "current_view_name"
[ImportMany(RequiredCreationPolicy=CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public IEnumerable<Lazy<MenuItem,IDictionary<string,object>> MenuItems
{
   set
   {
        var fooMenuItems = value
            .Where(x => x.Metadata["ContextTarget"] == "current_view_name")
            .Select(x => x.Value);
        // attach fooMenuItems to some context menu...
    }
}
```

but these methods need some custom arguments as well ! any ideas ?

Comment: Why are you so sure that the answer isn't `.Invoke("name", new object[] { sender, context });`?

Comment: @M.Babcock - The Question is how to call .Invoke() with the right args, pref. using MEF/Unity/AutoFac like method call builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to dynamically add context menus to your application via MEF, I would do something like this:

```
[Export(typeof(MenuItem)]
[ExportMetadata("ContextTarget", "foo")]
public FooMenuItemForBarAction
{
    get
    {
        var menuItem = new MenuItem("BarAction");
        menuItem.Click += delegate
        {
            // code to handle click here
        }
        return menuItem;
    }
}
```

And then elsewhere you can import all the context menu items for "foo" like this:

```
[ImportMany(RequiredCreationPolicy=CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public IEnumerable<Lazy<MenuItem,IDictionary<string,object>> MenuItems
{
   set
   {
        var fooMenuItems = value
            .Where(x => x.Metadata["ContextTarget"] == "foo")
            .Select(x => x.Value);
        // attach fooMenuItems to some context menu...
    }
}
```

For hotkey handlers you can do something similar: change the exported/imported type into an `Action` and replace the metadata by the key combo. Then when the user hits a key combo, you can scan all the imports for the one with the correct metadata and execute that action.

Comment: interesting idea, will def use this in another place but the Q here is a little different in that how to call the method with right params in the proper order

Comment: @kumar: you are still thinking in terms of Interop.Invoke. As I demonstrated, you don't need such dynamic method calls to make your application pluggable. MEF requires that you have a predefined contract which is exported by the plugins and imported by the plugin host.

Comment: what i am trying to say is that you have a property get where as i need a method call with various arguments ! I'll update in Q above

Comment: looking at your sample again, it,s a good way to model how to add the menuitem "label" but it does not address the "Action" and how to bind it io the menuitem which is what the Q refers to!